# Need admin rights to install Yahoo Messenger on a XP PC

Tags: windows-xp

As an administrator, how do I allow a user on her XP PC install yahoo messenger.  A message appears saying Need admin rights

The domain is a windows 2003 server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to install this one applicaiton, rather than giving the user the rights to install anything on their machine, you can use the run as administrator facility, but obviously you will have to do the installation.

On the machine, locate the setup file for Yahoo Messenger, hold down the shift key and right click the setup file. You will see the option to run as. Click this, enter your admin credentials in the box and click ok to start the install.

If you wish to allow her to install any software, without your interaction, you can make her a member of the Local Power Users or Administrators group (depending on how much access you want to give her) on her machine.

Unfortunatley there is no easy way to apply this to a specific group of users centraly by group policy. The only thing you could really do is create a group for users you want to allow software installation and then use restricted groups to add it to the local admin group on all workstations.

Comment: How about if they were to install other programs without my interaction.

Is there a policy that can control it on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change her rights on the PC by right-clicking on her active directory computer account and clicking on manage. That way, you don't have to walk over to her desk and do it yourself.